# Can't use alias within backticks inside bash script

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I have the following script:

```
for i in 1 2 3 
do
 alias echo${i}="echo ${i}"
 alias aliastest${i}="echo aliastest `echo${i}`"
done
```

after executing it, I'd expect to have 3 aliases in the names aliastest1, aliastest2, aliastest3.

However I'm getting:

```
./test.sh: line 5: echo1: command not found
./test.sh: line 5: echo2: command not found
./test.sh: line 5: echo3: command not found
```

Note that when trying to execute echo1, echo2, echo3 from command line, it does work as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Aliases are a bit weird to start with in `bash`; you should probably use a shell function instead. What is your *actual* use case? (This is either just a demo, or an exploration of some alias corner cases. Either way, it's not really worth delving into if you can use a shell function instead.)

Comment: Obviously it's just a simplified case of a real world problem, just to make it easier to post here. I accepted your suggestion and switched to functions. Thanks.

Comment: Similar: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196381/locally-created-alias-not-being-used-if-called-using-backticks

Answer (score 2):

Alias expansion is only enabled for interactive shells by default. You would need to add

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
```

to the beginning of the script.

It's likely that whatever alias you want to define, you should probably be defining as a shell function instead.

Comment: This is true but not the problem. The problem is that the embedded backtick command is being evaluated at alias assignment time because of the double quotes.

Comment: Thanks. Added this line, still the same.

Comment: @EtanReisner Hm. `echo1` should still be defined at that point, though; `echo $(alias)` would show the definition. There's either a bug or some subtlety that I"m overlooking in how the `alias` statement works.

Comment: Oh, true, the aliases should exist by that point (assuming they are usable there at all which they aren't by default). Hm... interestingly a small snippet like this works with `/bin/sh testalias.sh` but fails with `/bin/bash testalias.sh`. I wonder what's going on. (Where `/bin/sh` is bash `3.2.25(1)`.)